# Error while creating view on migrated document library

Tags: 2007, document-library, content-migration

I used the SharePoint Content Migration Tool from Codeplex to duplicate a library from a site to another (crossing the site collection boundary). The data passed through without any problem, but now when I try to create a new view on the library in the destination site, it throws me an error:

"the selected page contains a list that does not exists"

I checked the library AllItems.aspx code with SharePoint Designer to see if there was any reference to the old list GUID, but I couldn't find it.What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Does the site you are moving content from have publishing features enabled? If so, make sure the destination site has them enabled as well.